# request for comments on original crc32 checksum

Tags: c, crc32

Can someone explain to me why the crc is inverted twice ?

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Table of CRC-32's of all single-byte values (made by make_crc_table)
 */// definicao de uint e uchar

 #include <stdio.h>

//#define TEST 1

#ifndef uchar
#define uchar unsigned char
#endif

#ifndef uint
#define uint unsigned int
#endif

#ifndef ushort
#define ushort unsigned short
#endif

static const uint crc_table[256] = {
  0x00000000L, 0x77073096L, 0xee0e612cL, 0x990951baL, 0x076dc419L,
  0x706af48fL, 0xe963a535L, 0x9e6495a3L, 0x0edb8832L, 0x79dcb8a4L,
  0xe0d5e91eL, 0x97d2d988L, 0x09b64c2bL, 0x7eb17cbdL, 0xe7b82d07L,
  0x90bf1d91L, 0x1db71064L, 0x6ab020f2L, 0xf3b97148L, 0x84be41deL,
  0x1adad47dL, 0x6ddde4ebL, 0xf4d4b551L, 0x83d385c7L, 0x136c9856L,
  0x646ba8c0L, 0xfd62f97aL, 0x8a65c9ecL, 0x14015c4fL, 0x63066cd9L,
  0xfa0f3d63L, 0x8d080df5L, 0x3b6e20c8L, 0x4c69105eL, 0xd56041e4L,
  0xa2677172L, 0x3c03e4d1L, 0x4b04d447L, 0xd20d85fdL, 0xa50ab56bL,
  0x35b5a8faL, 0x42b2986cL, 0xdbbbc9d6L, 0xacbcf940L, 0x32d86ce3L,
  0x45df5c75L, 0xdcd60dcfL, 0xabd13d59L, 0x26d930acL, 0x51de003aL,
  0xc8d75180L, 0xbfd06116L, 0x21b4f4b5L, 0x56b3c423L, 0xcfba9599L,
  0xb8bda50fL, 0x2802b89eL, 0x5f058808L, 0xc60cd9b2L, 0xb10be924L,
  0x2f6f7c87L, 0x58684c11L, 0xc1611dabL, 0xb6662d3dL, 0x76dc4190L,
  0x01db7106L, 0x98d220bcL, 0xefd5102aL, 0x71b18589L, 0x06b6b51fL,
  0x9fbfe4a5L, 0xe8b8d433L, 0x7807c9a2L, 0x0f00f934L, 0x9609a88eL,
  0xe10e9818L, 0x7f6a0dbbL, 0x086d3d2dL, 0x91646c97L, 0xe6635c01L,
  0x6b6b51f4L, 0x1c6c6162L, 0x856530d8L, 0xf262004eL, 0x6c0695edL,
  0x1b01a57bL, 0x8208f4c1L, 0xf50fc457L, 0x65b0d9c6L, 0x12b7e950L,
  0x8bbeb8eaL, 0xfcb9887cL, 0x62dd1ddfL, 0x15da2d49L, 0x8cd37cf3L,
  0xfbd44c65L, 0x4db26158L, 0x3ab551ceL, 0xa3bc0074L, 0xd4bb30e2L,
  0x4adfa541L, 0x3dd895d7L, 0xa4d1c46dL, 0xd3d6f4fbL, 0x4369e96aL,
  0x346ed9fcL, 0xad678846L, 0xda60b8d0L, 0x44042d73L, 0x33031de5L,
  0xaa0a4c5fL, 0xdd0d7cc9L, 0x5005713cL, 0x270241aaL, 0xbe0b1010L,
  0xc90c2086L, 0x5768b525L, 0x206f85b3L, 0xb966d409L, 0xce61e49fL,
  0x5edef90eL, 0x29d9c998L, 0xb0d09822L, 0xc7d7a8b4L, 0x59b33d17L,
  0x2eb40d81L, 0xb7bd5c3bL, 0xc0ba6cadL, 0xedb88320L, 0x9abfb3b6L,
  0x03b6e20cL, 0x74b1d29aL, 0xead54739L, 0x9dd277afL, 0x04db2615L,
  0x73dc1683L, 0xe3630b12L, 0x94643b84L, 0x0d6d6a3eL, 0x7a6a5aa8L,
  0xe40ecf0bL, 0x9309ff9dL, 0x0a00ae27L, 0x7d079eb1L, 0xf00f9344L,
  0x8708a3d2L, 0x1e01f268L, 0x6906c2feL, 0xf762575dL, 0x806567cbL,
  0x196c3671L, 0x6e6b06e7L, 0xfed41b76L, 0x89d32be0L, 0x10da7a5aL,
  0x67dd4accL, 0xf9b9df6fL, 0x8ebeeff9L, 0x17b7be43L, 0x60b08ed5L,
  0xd6d6a3e8L, 0xa1d1937eL, 0x38d8c2c4L, 0x4fdff252L, 0xd1bb67f1L,
  0xa6bc5767L, 0x3fb506ddL, 0x48b2364bL, 0xd80d2bdaL, 0xaf0a1b4cL,
  0x36034af6L, 0x41047a60L, 0xdf60efc3L, 0xa867df55L, 0x316e8eefL,
  0x4669be79L, 0xcb61b38cL, 0xbc66831aL, 0x256fd2a0L, 0x5268e236L,
  0xcc0c7795L, 0xbb0b4703L, 0x220216b9L, 0x5505262fL, 0xc5ba3bbeL,
  0xb2bd0b28L, 0x2bb45a92L, 0x5cb36a04L, 0xc2d7ffa7L, 0xb5d0cf31L,
  0x2cd99e8bL, 0x5bdeae1dL, 0x9b64c2b0L, 0xec63f226L, 0x756aa39cL,
  0x026d930aL, 0x9c0906a9L, 0xeb0e363fL, 0x72076785L, 0x05005713L,
  0x95bf4a82L, 0xe2b87a14L, 0x7bb12baeL, 0x0cb61b38L, 0x92d28e9bL,
  0xe5d5be0dL, 0x7cdcefb7L, 0x0bdbdf21L, 0x86d3d2d4L, 0xf1d4e242L,
  0x68ddb3f8L, 0x1fda836eL, 0x81be16cdL, 0xf6b9265bL, 0x6fb077e1L,
  0x18b74777L, 0x88085ae6L, 0xff0f6a70L, 0x66063bcaL, 0x11010b5cL,
  0x8f659effL, 0xf862ae69L, 0x616bffd3L, 0x166ccf45L, 0xa00ae278L,
  0xd70dd2eeL, 0x4e048354L, 0x3903b3c2L, 0xa7672661L, 0xd06016f7L,
  0x4969474dL, 0x3e6e77dbL, 0xaed16a4aL, 0xd9d65adcL, 0x40df0b66L,
  0x37d83bf0L, 0xa9bcae53L, 0xdebb9ec5L, 0x47b2cf7fL, 0x30b5ffe9L,
  0xbdbdf21cL, 0xcabac28aL, 0x53b39330L, 0x24b4a3a6L, 0xbad03605L,
  0xcdd70693L, 0x54de5729L, 0x23d967bfL, 0xb3667a2eL, 0xc4614ab8L,
  0x5d681b02L, 0x2a6f2b94L, 0xb40bbe37L, 0xc30c8ea1L, 0x5a05df1bL,
  0x2d02ef8dL
};


/* =========================================================================
 * This function can be used by asm versions of crc32()
 */
const uint *   get_crc_table()
{
#ifdef DYNAMIC_CRC_TABLE
  if (crc_table_empty) make_crc_table();
#endif
  return (const uint *)crc_table;
}

/* ========================================================================= */
#define DO1(buf) crc = crc_table[((int)crc ^ (*buf++)) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);
#define DO2(buf)  DO1(buf); DO1(buf);
#define DO4(buf)  DO2(buf); DO2(buf);
#define DO8(buf)  DO4(buf); DO4(buf);

/* ========================================================================= */
uint   crc32(
    uint crc,
    const uchar *buf,
    uint len)
{
    if (buf == NULL) return 0L;
#ifdef DYNAMIC_CRC_TABLE
    if (crc_table_empty)
      make_crc_table();
#endif
    crc = crc ^ 0xffffffffL;
    while (len >= 8)
    {
      DO8(buf);
      len -= 8;
    }
    if (len) do {
      DO1(buf);
    } while (--len);
    return crc ^ 0xffffffffL;
}


#ifdef TEST

int main()
{

    printf("Testando crc \n");
        printf("%0.8x \n ", crc32(0,"ala", 1));



}


#endif
```

Comment: is that the full code?  It seems incomplete (considering that crc is not altered, apart from the inversions).  Are the `DOx` functions `#defines`?

Comment: common, this is the original crc32 implementation anyone is using it

Comment: #defines with unexpected side effects are evil

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in CRC checksums then this is a must-read:

http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt

Though it has been a long time since I've read it, so I'm not sure it will answer your specific question.

Edit: At least it contains the parameterization.

```
Here is the specification for the CRC-32 algorithm which is reportedly
used in PKZip, AUTODIN II, Ethernet, and FDDI.

   Name   : "CRC-32"
   Width  : 32
   Poly   : 04C11DB7
   Init   : FFFFFFFF
   RefIn  : True
   RefOut : True
   XorOut : FFFFFFFF
   Check  : CBF43926
```

Answer (score 1):

The first inversion is done because otherwise, adding leading zero bits to the buffer would not change the resulting CRC value (assuming the initial CRC value is zero).

I believe the inversion at the end is done so that this function can be called incrementally: Instead of having to call it on the entire data at once, you can call it in blocks, and the two inversions will cancel each other out on adjacent blocks.

Note that these inversions are not done on all CRC32 implementations.